# Can't connect to Google SQL Database with Python Script run in Google Functions

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform, database-connection, google-cloud-sql

The purpose of this python script is to pull data from google analytics and add it to a google MySQL database. The script works on my local machine, but not on google functions:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import os
from mysql.connector import errorcode


def main(data, context):

    # MySQL
    DB_NAME = 'GA_Data1'
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=user1, password=password1,
                                  host=hostip, database=DB_NAME)
```

When I run the code above I'm getting these errors:

- [error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXCQ8.png)

I think it might be because google's machine's IP address isn't white listed for my SQL database. I tried adding a cloud NAT with an external IP address so I could whitelist it. That didn't work. Here's a link to [an article that helps connect to a SQL database with python](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions#public-ip-default_1). Should I replace some of my code with the code in this article?

I'm resistant to changing anything because it works perfectly well on my computer. Therefore the problem lies somewhere with the running of the script on google's machines.

Comment: Do you use Cloud SQL?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes that is what I'm using.

Comment: Which IP do you use? The public one? The private one? Does a VPC connector work with a Cloud SQL private IP? What's wrong with the Cloud NAT? Can you detail your configuration?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for the help. Right now I have the option "route only requests to private IPs through the VPC connector" selected for my function. But I've tried both options. I'm using a private IP address for the SQL database right now. However, I have tried both public and private. I'm having a hard time answering your question well because I've tried all these things and the error messages haven't changed.

Comment: I guess that Cloud SQL and VPC Connector are in the same VPC, and in the same project, right? And even if you authorize the network 0.0.0.0/0 and use the pubilc IP it doesn't work?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere my Cloud SQL has a private IP and is associated with the "default" network. the serverless vpc that I have is under that same name. and the connector for the function has the name of the vpc.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I also tried with the public ip and authorizing the ip that didn't work. Could it be something else that I'm missing? or do you think this is a problem with the vpc connection?

Comment: Which IP did you authorized? the 0.0.0.0/0 range?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks for the help got the problem resolved below! was a problem in my actual script. Should have changed the ip to match the new private ip of the vpc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a VPC connector so that it can connect directly to the SQL server privately.

See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions

It's under "Networking" on egress side. You'll have to enable a few things in your Google Cloud Project, but it should walk you through it.

[image]

I'd recommend enabling the "Private IP" on the SQL database side.

[image]

And then using that private IP to connect in your function, and checking the box to only route private IPs on the Cloudfunction (in case you're doing a bunch of other stuff in there too):

[image]

Comment: Hi Mike thanks for the suggestion. I went through these steps and  I am still getting the same error. Unfortunately nothing has changed with the error message so I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Do you have a VPC connector listed on the Cloud Function, and do you use the "private IP" in your script (not the same one that works on your home computer)? @AndrewMarotta

Comment: Yes that worked thank you thank you!!!!! Now I'm getting other errors in the log. But hopefully I can work those out now!

Comment: Awesome, are they related to connecting to the DB, or totally different @AndrewMarotta